# Use a seed for json.Unmarshal into a slice struct

Tags: go

I have an interesting problem.

I want to make a request to an endpoint that gives me an array of objects back in an HTTP response.

I then want to unmarshal that response into a slice struct. Easy enough.

This code works:

```
type Human struct {}
func (h Human) Talk() {}

type CanTalk interface{
    Talk()
}

type Model struct {
    List []CanTalk
}

func main() {
    model := Model{}

    data, err := makeRequestToEndpoint()
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &model.List)
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }

    for _, human := range model.List {
        human.Talk()
    }
}
```

But here's the catch: I want to do this generically.

I don't want to write this same logic for every single type in my system (since they're all in separate files), so I opted to use an `interface{}` as opposed to `[]CanTalk`, so that I could abstract the unmarshal and logic below it to a utility function. The `interface{}` is then seeded with a concrete type for json.Unmarshal.

Even though this compiles and runs, it *does not* work:

```
type Human struct {}
func (h Human) Talk() {}

type CanTalk interface{
    Talk()
}

type Model struct {
    List interface{} // Using interface{} here instead of []CanTalk
}

func main() {
    model := Model{List:[]Human{}} // Seeding the list with the specified type to unmarshal into

    data, err := makeRequestToEndpoint()
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &model.List)
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }

    if list, ok := model.List.([]interface{}); ok {
        for i := range list {
            // This line is never reached, because "ok == false"
            if human, ok := list[i].(CanTalk); ok {
                // Never reached
                human.Talk()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the unmarshal does not pick up on the seed that I gave to `model.List`. The output of `model.List` after unmarshaling is still in the format of the HTTP response payload (a `map[string]interface{}` or something like that), not the type of the seed, hence the failure to cast into a `CanTalk` type.

Is this even possible, or would the only way to achieve this (short of real generics) be to repeat the unmarshal logic for each separate type in my system?

Comment: Unmarshal already takes an interface, all you need is to wrap the request+unmarshal logic into a func that takes an interface{} and then you can pass it values of concrete types.

Comment: ... here's an example of what i meant https://play.golang.com/p/8xQeQYOU_Af

Comment: @mkopriva Good idea, but that won't solve my problem. The same thing would occur: after unmarshaling, the `model.List` will be a slice of whatever came in the response in the form of maps (representing the JSON objects), as opposed to it being a slice of whatever seed struct I gave the `model.List`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Btw. your second example doesn't work because you didn't "seed" the list field with []interface{}... you seeded it with []Human. You should type assert the field's value to the type you used to seed the field with.

Comment: Well, a `[]Human{}` will conform to a `interface{}` type. `interface{}` will take anything. And since `Human` is a `CanTalk`, in theory my `list[i].(CanTalk)` should work. But it doesn't, and I suspect that's because the `json.Unmarshal` is ignoring the seed I give it. `list[i]` ends up being a `map[string]interface{}` or something like that, instead of a `Human`/`CanTalk`.

Comment: My bad, I completely missed that the List's element type is also an interface.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/D9KT4bsTOlc The problem seems to be that you're passing a pointer to the `interface{}` type instead of a pointer to the `[]Human` type.

Comment: @mkopriva Beautiful, thank you sir. Feel free to create an answer I can accept.

Comment: @mkopriva Actually, your examples *does* solve the unmarshal problem (now it unmarshals into the proper seed type), however, it does not solve the problem of the casting within loops. That is still unresolved. I need to cast into `[]interface{}`, not a `*[]Human`, because remember this logic is meant to be generic and used for many different concrete types. Appreciated solution regardless cause it brings me one step further. I think reflection is necessary for the last piece.